# Excel table does not expand automatically when data added by vba includes a hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

I have several excel workbooks that I want to consolidate in one excel table using the GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg) method.

When data is added by the macro to the bottom of the table, the table should expand automatically and transfer formulas and formats.

This works pretty well up to the point where I want to add a hyperlink:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Series").Cells(Irow, 3), _
                            Address:=fullpath, TextToDisplay:=GetValue(pfad, datei, blatt, "F3")
```

When including this line, the hyperlink is correctly entered, but the table will not expand. Without the hyperlink the table expands as supposed to.

Can anyone support here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code a line, before yours code :

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Series").Cells(Irow - 1, 3).ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. I just had to add an If clause to prevent an empty row at the end of the table.